# Output in http a .mp4 file, issue pulling from database to browser

Tags: mongodb, http, go, mux

**answered**

I am having a hard time with Mongodb and Gridfs, using it with Go's http package. I am trying to store a .mp4 file into Gridfs, then pull it out into the browser for playback.

> Heres what I am doing now. It successfully pulls the file from
>   database, I could even write it correctly to a download location.

```
// Connect to database
// Session to database

func movie(w http.ResponseWriter r *http.Request) {
    file, err := db.GridFS("fs").Open("movie.mp4")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    w.Header.Set("Content-type", "video/mp4")
    if _, err := io.Copy(w, file); err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
    } 
    // I am trying to send it to the browser.
    // I want to achieve same thing as, http://localhost/view/movie.mp4, 
    as if you did that.
}
```

If the file was on the server, I would just do something like this. But instead I am trying to store it in Mongodb, for all around easier use involving metadata.

```
func movie(w http.ResponseWriter r *http.Request) {
    http.ServeFile("./uploads/movie.mp4") // Easy
}
```

The browser is receiving something, but its just malformed or corrupted. Just shows the video player with an error message. Any help would be appreciated, I have only been programming a week.

Here is a picture of the error, no console error messages.

[image]

> Unless someone has an alternative to storing video files for playback
>   in browser somewhere other than MongoDB or Amazon S3. Please let me know,
>   thanks.

Comment: Please show the webconsole error.

Comment: I uploaded the picture of the error, Browser is safari. It does not have any console error messages. I don't know why this happens, but if I do **http.ServeFile(".mp4")** you can visit the /video.mp4 url and it loads the default safari  player.

Comment: This `io.Copy(w, r)` is a typo right? You're not actually trying to write the request to the response but the `file`, right?

Comment: And please do check the error returned from `io.Copy`.

Comment: io.Copy has no error, and no the io.Copy is not a typo. I am new and thats what I thought I was supposed to do, to write the file into the browser. I want the file written in the response, and be able to play.

Comment: Do this instead: `if _, err := io.Copy(w, file); err != nil { // handle error`

Comment: I added the if your error handling, it still does not send the file in the **response** correctly. This must be browser problem, something with the headers maybe?

Comment: `r` is not the file, `r` is the request you got from the client, copying that into `w` makes little sense.

Comment: Oh if I did that sorry I re-typed it for stack overflow incorrectly. But, yes were are writing out to the browser not the request. Do I need to read over the bytes first and decode it, then send it out? I wouldn't even know how to begin with that. I am thinking it must be a header issue, with **content-length** and bytes.

Comment: Try the solution from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38069584/golang-http-webserver-provide-video-mp4

Comment: I can not use ServeFile, because I am using a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check `http.ServeContent`. It will handle all the mess (content-type, content-length, partial data, cache) automaticlly and save you a lot of time. It takes a ReadSeeker to serve, which GridFile already implented. So your code may simply change to the below.

```
func movie(w http.ResponseWriter r *http.Request) {
    file, err := db.GridFS("fs").Open("movie.mp4")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    http.ServeContent(w,r,"movie.mp4",file.UploadDate(),file)

}
```

If that doesn't work, please use tools like curl or wget to download the served content and compare it to the orignal one (in db).