# serve video with go gin

Tags: go, go-gin

I am writing a api server for upload and serve video and image by go-gin framework. I have uploaded my video to another host, and it worked

```golang
router := gin.Default()

    //config := cors.DefaultConfig()
    //config.AllowAllOrigins = true

    routerConfig := cors.Config{
        AllowAllOrigins:  true,
        AllowMethods:     []string{"GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"},
        AllowHeaders:     []string{"X-Requested-With", "Authorization", "Origin", "Content-Length", "Content-Type"},
        AllowCredentials: false,
        MaxAge:           12 * time.Hour,
    }

    router.Use(cors.New(routerConfig))

    router.StaticFS("/public", http.Dir("static"))

    err := router.Run(":5000")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
```

When I try to access `http://localhost:5000/public/{image_url}.png` by chromium. It loads to browser. But when I access `http://localhost:5000/public/{video_url}.mp4` by chromium, it can't load anything from browser (It can't receive)

Can someone explain for me what I am doing wrong?

**Update:**

Maybe I missed this content:

[image]

[image]

Here are my 2 http packages when I call a `GET` request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 possible explanation for your problem.

1. It's not a problem because your browser doesn't have any feature to run video.
2. (This is more possible explanation) You don't set the correct header for streaming video so the browser can't recognize or don't know what to do with that URL.

For example I get from this [video](https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4), when you check the Response Header, it should show

```
content-length: 1570024
content-range: bytes 0-1570023/1570024
content-type: video/mp4
```

My suggestion is use [http.ServeFile](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeFile) which supports serving Range requests. See related questions, [**GoLang http webserver provide video (mp4)**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38069584/golang-http-webserver-provide-video-mp4) and [**How to serve http partial content with Go?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36540610/how-to-serve-http-partial-content-with-go).

**Updated**

After checking [Gin StaticFS Godoc](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin), I don't think it support Range header.

**After Test**

So I have try your code and I'm wrong, **Gin StaticFS can serve content range like video**.

Here my screenshot, have tested it using Chromium and it works well:

[image: load test.mp4]

And my conclusions: There is a problem with your Chromium or your codecs or your video codecs not supported on your OS (I don't know what is your OS), check this [MP4 not playing on Chrome version 27.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17025162/6118551):

> due to Chrome removing support for h264, on some machines, mp4 videos encoded with it will either not work (throwing an Parser error when viewing under Firebug/Network tab - consistent with issue submitted here), or crash the browser, depending upon the encoding settings

> it isn't consistent - it entirely depends upon the codecs installed on the computer - while I didn't encounter this issue on my machine, we did have one in the office where the issue occurred (and thus we used this one for testing)

> it might to do with Quicktime / divX settings (the machine in question had an older version of Quicktime than my native one - we didn't want to loose our testing pc though, so we didn't update it).

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. Can you check again for my question pls?

Comment: hi, I'll try to simulate this one and update my answer a.s.a.p.

Comment: check my edited answer, check your supported codecs on your OS, test the chromium with other static video link on internet, and try to change your browser

Comment: Thanks for your support. But my problem may be actually come from my upload video. I don't know why, but when I update other files, it turn to be worked.

Comment: Because I have use opencv for encode video before that

Comment: aha....so it's the video then....so it's already running, right?

Comment: Yeah. I change the codex of it and it can be played through browser. But now, it can not be played in local ...

Comment: hem...weird...but anyway, it's another topic, so maybe you can post new question about that :-D