# Stream video in Go lang server

Tags: go, video-streaming, html5-video

I've written this simple http server to serve video file:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "bytes"
    "io"
    "fmt"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

rangeValue := r.Header.Get("range")
fmt.Println("Range:")
fmt.Println(rangeValue)

buf := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
f, _ := os.Open("oceans_1.webm")
io.Copy(buf, f)           // Error handling elided for brevity.
f.Close()

w.Header().Set("Accept-Ranges","bytes")
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "video/webm")
w.Header().Set("Content-Length","22074728")
w.Header().Set("Last-Modified", "Wed, 29 Nov 2017 17:10:44 GMT")

w.WriteHeader(206)
w.Write(buf.Bytes())
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

The video is served perfect, but I can not change time of the video. When I click on the timeline video cursor it doesn't change the position and the video doesn't jump to specific time.

When I serve the video using `http.ServeFile(w, r, "oceans_1.webm")` everything works perfect - I can change video time.

Comment: Because seeking the video at client side requires support for partial content serving from the server. See possible duplicate: [How to serve http partial content with Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36540610/how-to-serve-http-partial-content-with-go)

Answer (score 4):

This different behavior is directly addressed on the `net/http` package, on the documentation for [ServeContent](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeContent) (emphasis mine):

> ServeContent replies to the request using the content in the provided ReadSeeker. **The main benefit of ServeContent over io.Copy is that it handles Range requests properly**, sets the MIME type, and handles If-Match, If-Unmodified-Since, If-None-Match, If-Modified-Since, and If-Range requests.

If you check the `net/http` code, you'll see that [`ServeFile`](https://golang.org/src/net/http/fs.go#L662) calls [`serveContent`](https://golang.org/src/net/http/fs.go#L180) (through [`serveFile`](https://golang.org/src/net/http/fs.go#L540)), which is the same unexported function called by [`ServeContent`](https://golang.org/src/net/http/fs.go#L151).

I've not digged into the reason for the different behaviors, but the documentation on the package makes quite clear why your `io.Copy` strategy is not working, while the `http.ServeFile` does.

Comment: BTW, as @icza said in the comment to the original question, the reason for this different behavior (that I had not digged in), is clearly explained in [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36540610/how-to-serve-http-partial-content-with-go).